# Geometrical Isomerism of Metal Complex

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds

Does $\ce{Ni((en)2(Cl)2)}$ show cis-trans form ?

And if No

Why not ?

Comment: Sounds like a homework question. Can you post what you think are the cis- and trans- forms of this compound?

Comment: The question is asked whether the compound will show geometric isomerism . I think it should show cis-trans  but the answer says no. I can't figure out why , are bidentate ligands always bonded to adjacent sites of the geometry ?

Comment: If you draw en, then you can see that there is no way for it to reach all the way around the molecule to bond to a trans position.  (I think it's the smallest bidentate ligand.)

Comment: I can draw a cis (w/r/t the Cl ligands) form, so if it does not exist (i.e. has never been observed), then why would that be (which is what the question is really asking)?

Comment: Theoretically you can draw both situation; when monodentate ligands replaced with bidentate ligands cis- trans- isomers can be drawed (in ML2B2 type). How did you have an answer that says "no" ?

Answer (score 3):

$\ce{en}$ is bidenate so it has to take two neighbour corners from octahedron (let say equatorial position). The second $\ce{en}$ can bind with 1st nitrogen also on equator but then the 2nd has a choice: it can bind in equator or on axial position. So in theory it would be possible to see two isomers. The reality has however more to do with energy. $\ce{en}$ is very good ligand and $\ce{Ni++}$ makes very stable quadratic planar complexes. For that reason both $\ce{en}$ goes into equatorial position and the weaker ligands $\ce{Cl-}$ occupy axial positions.